# How to drop "GRAPH" on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to drop graph. An error occurred when dropping graph.

```
# drop graph graph;
ERROR:  cannot drop graph graph because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  sequence graph.ag_label_seq depends on schema graph
label ag_vertex depends on schema graph
label ag_edge depends on schema graph
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

How to drop "GRAPH"?

Comment: probably, # drop graph graph cascade; ?

Answer (score 0):

When dropping graph, all data & schema must be drop before.

For convenience, optional "CASCADE" clause is usable.

```
# drop graph graph cascade;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 3 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to sequence graph.ag_label_seq
drop cascades to label ag_vertex
drop cascades to label ag_edge
DROP GRAPH
```